# ControllerAdvice not handling exception

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, exception, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 1.3.3 application. I have a rest controller that throws an exception in certain situations. The exceptions are being thrown and the message printed but the ControllerAdvice class is not being fired. Here's my relevant files:
TestController.java

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    // RESTful method
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/test",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonNode fooRestTest(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders header,
            @RequestBody String payload) {
        ControllerUtil.validateHeaders(header);
        return null;
    }
}
```

ControllerUtil.java

```
public class ControllerUtil {
    public static void validateHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
        if(headers.get("test-field") == null) {
            throw new InvalidHeaderException("Invalid test-field in header");
        }
    }
}
```

InvalidHeaderException.java

```
public class InvalidHeaderException extends RuntimeException {


    public InvalidHeaderException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public InvalidHeaderException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

AppErrorController.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidHeaderException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleHeaderError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", ex);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.addObject("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        mav.addObject("status", 400);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="RBGApp" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>FooTester</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Foo_Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mappings -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Foo_Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

MvcConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getJspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I tested this with a request from postman and it throws the exception and prints out the line:

```
Invalid test-field in header
```

But the code never goes into the `AppErrorController` at all. So none of the other values like `timestamp` are populated. Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

**Edit 1:**
This is what postman spits out as the response:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Invalid test-field in header</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Exception report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Invalid test-field in header</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>exception</b>
            <pre>controllers.exceptions.InvalidHeaderException: Invalid test-field in header
    controllers.util.ControllerUtil.validateHeaders(ControllerUtil.java:12)
    controllers.TestController.fooRestTest(TestController.java:77)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>note</b>
            <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 logs.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.62</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2:** Console output when making the postman request

```
09:08:14.373 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'Foo_Test' processing POST request for [/TEST]
09:08:14.381 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test
09:08:14.390 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode controllers.AlertController.getAlertsForRest(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,java.lang.String)]
09:08:14.390 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'alertController'
09:08:14.426 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Read [class java.lang.String] as "application/json" with [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@4732b26d]
09:08:14.436 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode controllers.AlertController.getAlertsForRest(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,java.lang.String)]: controllers.exceptions.InvalidHeaderException: Invalid test-field in header
09:08:14.439 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode controllers.AlertController.getAlertsForRest(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,java.lang.String)]: controllers.exceptions.InvalidHeaderException: Invalid test-field in header
09:08:14.439 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode controllers.AlertController.getAlertsForRest(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,java.lang.String)]: controllers.exceptions.InvalidHeaderException: Invalid test-field in header
09:08:14.443 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
controllers.exceptions.InvalidHeaderException: Invalid test-field in header
    controllers.util.ControllerUtil.validateHeaders(ControllerUtil.java:12)
    controllers.TestController.fooRestTest(TestController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: ...can you add a log statement and double check that? It looks like it's fine the way it is configured.

Comment: Updated my post. As you can see the ControllerAdvice isn't contributed at all to this response. There should be a timestamp field and the error code should be 400.

Comment: Can you delete the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation from that controller and try again. Do you have the project somewhere (Bitbucket, GitHub, GitLab) so we can take a look? Also, you never set the `viewName`, not sure how it knows where to go...

Comment: What makes you think that returning a model (there is no view) with "status" being 400 does change the outcome of some exception being thrown?? see also https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Do you have messages like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument` in your log files?

Try to use same exception type at *handleHeaderError* method argument: *InvalidHeaderException* instead of *Exception*. Like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppErrorController {

@ExceptionHandler(InvalidHeaderException.class)
public ModelAndView handleHeaderError(HttpServletRequest req, InvalidHeaderException ex) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", ex);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.addObject("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    mav.addObject("status", 400);
    return mav;
}
```

}

Comment: i tried this and it still didn't work. I posted the console output. There's no `IllegalStateException` being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is some other handler that is Handling this request(`from first 5 lines of console output`). That might be in any of the jars that are in the build path of your project.

We need to set priority of your handler as Highest, so control comes here first.

I think adding `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` after `@EnableWebMvc` might solve the problem.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AppErrorController {

@ExceptionHandler(InvalidHeaderException.class)
public ModelAndView handleHeaderError(HttpServletRequest req, InvalidHeaderException ex) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", ex);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.addObject("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    mav.addObject("status", 400);
    return mav;
}
```

Also if it doesn't work try changing `InvalidHeaderException.class` to `Exception.class` (Regardless of what exception it is control would come here). Also debugging would be helpful in your case.